# Relative path when given a directory

Tags: path

I was told to give the relative path of the absolute path /u/user1/f2/456 starting from directory /u/user1/f1/123

The thing I don't get is f1 and f2 are on the same level, and my directory starts inside f1, but I need to get to f2 for my relative path. I tried both user1/f2/456 and f2/456, but apparently both of these are not the relative path.

Comment: Did you try: `../../f2/456` ?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using a relative path, you can go back to the directory above with `..`

So to get from `/u/user1/f1/123` to `/u/user1/f2/456`, first you want to get back to the user1 directory.

`../` now in f1
`../` now in user1
`/f2` now in f2
`/456` now in the target directory
So the relative path is `../../f2/456`